# How to get data from Google Analytics 360 into Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, google-analytics

I hope you are understand my unclear question. 
please helping me out.

I've followed document that provided by Salesforce and I've integrated with Marketing Cloud and Google Analytics 360. it was very simple.

and then, I was trying to use Google Analytics Data as Entry Source in Journey,
but Actually, I can't use that. because I don't know even what data is inject to the Google Analytics Entry Source. So, I've looked around Data Extension in Contact Builder, but I didn't find Google Analytics Data Extension.

I thought there would be a data table with Google Analytics 360 data.
but there's nothing exist.

How does it works and how can it be used to in journey builder in order to Customer Journey based on GA 360 Data?

Please let me know what that I missed and How to use Google Analytics Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the integration has been done properly (as an Administrator in both sides), you should be able to see it in Contact Builder / Data Sources. The only data you can synchronize from GA 360 to SFMC is the [audiences](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2611404?hl=en), that once they are assigned to the Marketing Cloud user in the setup in GA, are automatically choosable in the entry source of the journey.

Comment: Hello fromero! Thank you for the answer.
Integration has already done. I can see Google Analytics 360 Data Source at the Synchronized External Audiences Section in Contact Builder. Also, I can select my audience created by Google Analytics using Google Audience Entry Source in Journey Builder. But, I don't know how does it work what that exactly operate with Marketing Cloud and Google Analytics. From what I saw that can able to select my audience in Journey Builder, it is obviously increasing count number. But, I cannot find that the data is what places stored.

Comment: Have a look at the FAQs https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai360_faq.htm&type=0, I think it will help you to understand how it works. As far as I know, you can only use information coming from GA.

Comment: Thanks! as follow you provided documentation link, I've understood as more than I had thought. also, there have a lots of information about Integration. but, still I don't understand one thing. So, I want to make sure that my comprehension. the parts of document is explain " Data Extension doesn't stored Data From Google Analytcis.". does mean that Google Analytics only use the Entry Source and just based on data from Google Analytcis Environments?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Google Analytics works only based on data coming from Google 
 Analytics, nothing related to Data Extensions or other sources.

Comment: Thanks! I've understood. I really appreciate you helping me out. I hope you having a great day! Thanks again : )