# How to view the subscriber information in a GA360 audience?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, google-analytics, datasource

GA360 audience is used as entry source and it shows a DE that is refreshed daily. I am aware that GA360 only pushes the subscriber IDs back to marketing cloud. I would like to query this DE in an automation so that we can uplift the connector capabilities.

I read in Cameron Robert's blog that we could potentially query the DE - https://www.cameronrobert.com.au/sfmc/getting-value-from-your-ga360-connector/
We don't have a Marketing Cloud Connector so we don't have a Synchronized DE folder! How do we query this DE and get the subscriber details?

[image]

Image from [Google Analytics Audience as Entry Source in Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305769/google-analytics-audience-as-entry-source-in-journey-builder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data from Google Analytics 360 into Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293599/how-to-get-data-from-google-analytics-360-into-marketing-cloud)

Comment: what subscriber details are you looking for?

Comment: I am aware that GA360 only pushes the subscriber IDs back to marketing cloud. I would like to query this DE in an automation so that we can uplift the connector capabilities. Hope that helps!